# Creating an array of the difference between items in another array

Tags: arrays, ruby, date-difference

My goal is to create an array on integers, each representing the days elapsed between two dates. Eventually I’ll average and do other operations on it.

I’ve reached working code:

```rb
require 'date'

dates = ['2020-01-30', '2020-01-24', '2020-01-16'].map { |d| Date.parse(d) }

day_difference = []

dates.each_index do |index|
  begin
    day_difference.push((dates[index] - dates[index + 1]).to_i)
  rescue TypeError # end of array
    break
  end
end
```

But I’m wondering if there’s a cleaner way, without having to look out for the last index value. Ruby arrays have a lot of methods, so I wouldn’t be surprised if one of those held a better solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
require 'date'
```

```
dates = ['2020-01-30', '2020-01-24', '2020-01-16']
```

```
dates.map { |s| DateTime.strptime(s, '%Y-%m-%d').to_date }.
      each_cons(2).map { |d1,d2| (d1-d2).to_i }
  #=> [6, 8]
```

Change `(d1-d2)` to `(d2-d1)` if desired.

See [Enumerable#each_cons](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.7.0/Enumerable.html#method-i-each_cons).

One could map just once by writing

```
dates.each_cons(2).map { |s1,s2| (DateTime.strptime(s1, '%Y-%m-%d').to_date -
  DateTime.strptime(s2, '%Y-%m-%d').to_date).to_i }
```

but that has the disadvantage that `strptime` must be applied twice to `dates.size-2` of the date strings.

[Date#parse](https://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.7.0/libdoc/date/rdoc/Date.html#method-c-parse) should only be used (instead of `DateTime::strptime`) if one has a high degree of confidence that the date strings will all be in the proper format. (Try
`Date.parse("Parse may work or may not work")`.)

Answer (score 2):

You can solve it in one loop with [Enumerable#each_with_object](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.7.1/Enumerable.html#method-i-each_with_object) and [Enumerator#with_index](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.7.1/Enumerator.html#method-i-with_index) methods.

```
dates = ['2020-01-30', '2020-01-24', '2020-01-16']

day_difference = dates.each_with_object([]).with_index do |(date, arr), index|
  next if index == dates.size - 1

  arr << (Date.parse(date) - Date.parse(dates[index + 1])).to_i
end
```